# What does this piece of code mean? (c.matches(`.${filters.join('.')}`))

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript code to filter some `divs` with some `buttons`, but I don't really understand what this piece of code means.

```
c.matches(`.${filters.join('.')}`)
```

The full code of that part is:

```
sheets.forEach((c) => {
    if (filters.length === 0 || c.matches(`.${filters.join('.')}`)) {
      c.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      c.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Do you have `filters` declared anywhere? using ${} inside of \` will interpret any variables, so \`${filters}\` would put in the value of `filters`

Comment: And with what part do you have problems with? With [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), with [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) or with [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: The `const filters = [...document.querySelectorAll('.btn.active')].map(
    (el) => el.dataset.filter,
  );` is declared here yes. It's like classical music or Renaissance, ...

Comment: Well I don't understand those `match` and `join ` in this context. Don't get what it matches and joins

Comment: Without knowing the contents of `filters` it is not possible to tell you what it exactly does.

Comment: For those wondering, here is the last approved answer for this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74306849/3684265

Comment: Just to help you if your are a beginner, I wouldn’t recommend you just using code you don’t understand and copied from anywhere

Comment: @Sumin If you ask followup a question it would be greate to link to original question.

Comment: Based on the previous question matches is about [`Element.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)?

Comment: Yes, about the `element.matches` .

Comment: `element.matches(selector)` returns true if the element matches the CSS selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filters` is an array of class names, and `filters.join('.')` will concatenate them all with `.` between them. The template literal will put `.` before this. So if `filters` is `['class1', 'class2', 'class3']`, the resulting string will be `.class1.class2.class3`.

The `Element.matches()` method returns `true` if the element matches the given CSS selector. So in the above example, this is `c.matches('.class1.class2.class3')` if the element `c` has all 3 classes.

So what this code does is filter the sheets so that only the ones matching all the classes in the filter list are shown.